# Binding a ListView to an array of objects

Tags: android, listview

I have an array of `Password` objects, each containing a `tag`, a `username` and a `password` (all of three `String`s).

I'd like to display the `tag`s contained in each `Password` in a `ListView`.

I thought about using an `ArrayAdapter` linked to a `String` array containing only the `tag`s, but I'm almost sure this would be a bad option as I plan to update frequently the `Password` array's contents.

Is there any other option to bind my `Password` array to a `ListView` and making it display only its `tag` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution:

Step #1: Implement `toString()` on `Password` to return `tag`

Step #2: Put your `Password` objects in an `ArrayList<Password>`

Step #3: Put your `ArrayList<Password>` into an `ArrayAdapter<Password>`

Step #4: Put your `ArrayAdapter<Password>` into your `ListView`

Comment: Since my Password list is inside a third class and I get it by calling a toArrayList() method on this third class, how do I notify the adapter about changes in the array list?

Comment: @Federico Culloca: Possibly you do not use an `ArrayAdapter`, but rather a custom `BaseAdapter` on "this third class". Regardless, calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `Adapter` will let it know about changes in the underlying data.